# Magento PayPal order - Money taken - Not showing as an order in the backend

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal, sales

Hi so as of a few days ago PayPal orders are being charged but no order appears in the backend and no customer emails are sent.

I went into PayPal IPN settings and the return URL was:
http://example.com/credit/ppcb.asp

I did some looking around and tried:
http://www.example.com/index.php/paypal/standard/success/

I did the checkout myself, it goes to a success page and gives me an order number but this never goes into the Sales grid and no confirmation email is sent.

I am just stumped if anyone can suggest anything that would be great!

**EDIT:
A few errors that are appearing around the time of the order system.log**

> 2015-08-19T08:58:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 3 for Mage_Review_Block_Helper::getSummaryHtml(), called in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/site1/app/design/frontend/default/sns_nova/template/sns/ajaxcart/checkout/cart/mini-cart/default.phtml on line 176 and defined  in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/site1/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Helper.php on line 41
>
> 2015-08-19T08:58:13+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: displayIfNoReviews  in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/site1/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Helper.php on line 49
>
> 2015-08-19T08:58:15+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/site1/app/code/local/Sns/Ajaxcart/Block/Cart/Ajaxcart.php on line 36

Comment: In newer versions of Magento the IPN is irrelevant as it is provided to Paypal by Magento dynamically, in your example I would say the IPN is not correct unless you are processing it via some other external (Microsoft *spit*) code. Even with the wrong IPN you would still see the Order in the backend. Are you using paypal standard or express? Do other payment methods work? The logged errors don't seem to be associated with orders.

Comment: Hi I am using the standard PayPal. I too noticed that the URL makes no difference as it takes me to the same place everytime! That is all the errors there is so I have no idea how to fogure out why they arent going into the backend! ALso all other payment methods are working.

Comment: Did anything change recently? What version of Magento are you using? Do you have a development server where you can replicate the problem, or restore to an earlier backup of your store to see if the problem existed then. Have you installed any new modules in the last few days?

Comment: I used ssh to list all files changed in the app and skin folder at/before the time i stopped working. Any that were changed backups were restored and it still didn't work. They all didn't seem related anyway. No new modules, I would just like to see a nice error that was telling me why it wasn't inserting!